# JIT コンパイルの条件

Tags: android

Dalvik　VM の JITコンパイルはどのような条件のときに行われているのでしょうか.
例えば,呼び出し回数が多いのような条件があれば教えてください

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-jit-compiler-androids-dalvik-vm.pdf

この資料をざっと読んだだけなので詳しい説明はできませんが、DalvikのJITは`Tracing JIT`を採用しています。つまり、メソッド単位ではなく実行回数の多いコードパスを検出してJITコンパイルするようになっています。

メソッド単位でのコンパイルは最適化の面では効果的ですが、メモリ使用量が多くコンパイルに時間がかかるためモバイルデバイスには不向きだと判断されています。

> Leave open the possibility of supplementing with methodbased JIT

ただし、メソッド単位のJITを補助的に利用する余地を残しておく、とも書かれていますので実際はメソッド単位でのコンパイルも行われているかもしれません。